# How to plot maximal intensity projection of images in same directory

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have a Z-stack of images of biological samples.
Each biological sample is saved in its own directory : Sample_1, Sample_2...
Each image of the Z-stack is saved alone : Sample_1/position_1.tif, Sample_1/position_2.tif, Sample_1/position_3.tif...

How can I plot with opencv (or any other python library) **the maximal intensity projection of each biological sample** ?

I found here ([Maximum intensity projection from image stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178916/maximum-intensity-projection-from-image-stack/52085463)) an answer that is close but my original images are not stacks but separated images.

Please, could you let me know if you have any clue in order to solve my issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make the stack of images thanks to this post : [Create Numpy array of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747021/create-numpy-array-of-images).

Once the list of images is done, convert it to numpy array.

Then apply function numpy.max() as explained in [Maximum intensity projection from image stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178916/maximum-intensity-projection-from-image-stack/52085463).

I hope this would help people with same kind of problem ^^